# How to convert this line of code into Vb.NET?

Tags: vb.net, vb6-migration

I have been working for VB6.0 and trying to convert that code into VB.NET.Alomost I tried and succeed but when I am confused to convert this lines of code.

```
If Not ds.EOF Then
      ds.MoveFirst()
      ds.MoveLast()
End If
```

Can Any one help me to convert this lines of Code ?any one tell me some online VB6 to VB.NET converter tools.

I have used SQlDataReader instead of the RecordSet.I think while seeing this lines of code I thought ds.MoveFirst(),ds.MoveLast() means moving the cursor postion of the recordSet to last record

Comment: What type of object is `ds`? Is it a recordset?

Comment: In isolation, I too am confused about what that code snippet is trying to achieve. Any chance you could post a bit more of the code?

Comment: I have used SQlDataReader instead of the RecordSet.I think while seeing this lines of code I thought ds.MoveFirst(),ds.MoveLast() means moving the cursor postion of the recordSet to last record

Comment: @Hemant: You should always edit your question instead of commenting it. Then others would see it immediately and i could undo my downvote ;) Btw, you cannot(better: should not)move a reader to the last position. That would mean you would read all from database even if you only want the last. Why not selecting only the last by using `SELECT TOP 1... ORDER BY ...` in the first place? That's the reason why a `SqlDataReader` doesnt have this methods.

Answer (score 2):

The VB.NET recordset is a [`DataReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.data.datareader.read.aspx), for example a [`SqlDataReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.aspx). It has a [`Read`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.read.aspx) method which advances the reader to the next block of data in cases where the reader contains more than one block and returns a `bool` that indicates if there are more blocks of data to read.

For example:

```
Using con = New SqlConnection(connectionString)
    Using cmd = New SqlCommand("SELECT IntCol,StringCol,BoolCol FROM Table WHERE ...", con)
        con.Open()
        Using rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader()
            While rdr.Read()
                Dim IntCol = rdr.GetInt32(0)
                Dim StringCol = rdr.GetString(1)
                Dim BoolCol = rdr.GetBoolean(2)
            End While
        End Using
    End Using
End Using
```

Note that there's no `MoveFirst` or `MoveLast` in ADO.NET.

You  should not move a reader to the last position. That would mean you would read all data from database even if you only want the last record. Why not selecting only the last by using `SELECT TOP 1 ... ORDER BY ...` in the first place? That's the reason why a `SqlDataReader` doesnt have these methods.

Another way would be to use a [`DataTable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.aspx) if you want to do that in memory. Then you can access the last row by `table.Rows(table.Rows.Count-1)`. You can load a `DataTable` via [`SqlDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/905keexk).

Comment: Can we skip those lines of Code ?

Comment: @Hemant: I think the code goes to the last and then the first so that it can get a valid row count. If you read into a `DataTable` you will have a row count and can skip that code.

Comment: @Hemant: I don't know the purpose of these lines without more context. Imho that is weird. It advances the  current record position to the first record and then it immediately moves the current record position to the last record without any other action. So if you ask me you can skip that. But i'm not familiar with VB6. If you only want the record count, you should not use a DataTable but [`SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx) with the appropriate sql like: `SELECT COUNT(*)AS Count FROM TABLE WHERE [Condition]`.